# Is a low popularity of a political party leader typically used as a reason for asking to resign within Western democracies?

Tags: parties, political-leaders

Recently, the main Romanian party in power had another internal issue when [some important persons asked its leader to resign](https://www.rferl.org/a/top-romanian-social-democrat-members-urge-party-leader-to-resign/29499981.html) via an [open letter](https://www.actmedia.eu/daily/open-letter-for-dragnea-s-resignation/77457):

> Top politicians in Romania’s ruling Social Democrats (PSD) have called
>   on the party leader to step down over criminal corruption convictions
>   and party-related violations.

I cannot find an English transcript of the letter, but one of the many reasons behind asking him to step down was that he has a much lower popularity than party popularity.

I have also heard political analysts arguing that a high discrepancy between leader popularity (significantly lower) and party popularity is a strong reason for the leader to step down (the expression used is that the leader should be like a locomotive for the party, not the other way around) either nicely or by force.

I am wondering if such reasoning is used in Western democracies.

**Question:** Is a low popularity of a political party leader typically used as a reason for asking to resign?

Comment: In Britain no one normally resigns unless they are forced, either by a vote of no confidence in the House of Commons, or by the constitutional procedure of their political party. However a party leader who has been defeated e.g. in a General Election may voluntarily resign e.g. Neil Kinnock 1992.

Comment: @WS2 - yes, but is his/her low popularity (lower that that of the party) invoked when being asked for resign or are there typically other reasons?

Comment: Anthony Eden resigned as Prime Minister and leader of the Conservative Party in 1956, following the Suez crisis. But I think the reason of his poor health was used as an explanation. Harold Wilson voluntarily resigned, but that was described as retirement. Heath and Thatcher were both forced out by votes in the party.

Comment: What do you mean by "asking to resign"? Anyone can ask the party leader to resign, there is nothing to forbid asking. And the leader simply may say "No".

Comment: @Thern - yes, that is true. I am looking for contexts when some party members say something like this: "hey, you, party leader, your popularity is way lower that party's popularity, you should resign". I am not interested in whether the leader resigns or not.

Comment: There should be an abundance of such cases. I have not much time currently, but I will look into some German sources. Pretty sure that at least the (in his final years extremely unpopular) German chancellor Helmut Kohl faced this problem, but I don't remember which politician said what twenty years ago.

Comment: @Alexei A very good example is that of [Margaret Thatcher, a Prime Minister undefeated at the polls, the winner of three general elections, who was forced out by a ballot of her party members.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premiership_of_Margaret_Thatcher#1990_leadership_challenge_and_resignation) But she certainly did not resign voluntarily.

Comment: @WS2 - you can provide an answer based on this article. The fact that she did not resign voluntarily is irrelevant for my question.

Comment: @WS2 You've basically provided enough information to create a vote worthy answer.  Please make an answer and feel free to elaborate a bit more.

Comment: FWIW, there isn't a uniform answer across Western democracies. For example, the U.S. differs in norms on this question from systems with a parliamentary system where MPs elect a Prime Minister.

Comment: This pretty much what happened to John Boehner in 2015.  There had been a previous election to remove him, but it didn't pass.  By the time a major spending bill, Boehner's polling numbers among Republican voters had fallen to 40% approval rating.  He resigned from political office at the end of October of that year, and his role as Speaker of the House was followed up by Paul Ryan.